# Activities on the custoized backstack recreating

Tags: android

I have four activities
 A->B->C->D 
where A is parent of B ,B of C and c of D.
I have animations specified for onCreate and onBackPressed

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);}
```

and

```
 public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left,R.anim.push_out_right);
}
```

On user input from some other activity i am launching activity D using following code

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,D.class);
        TaskStackBuilder.create(this).addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent).startActivities();
```

As expected D is launched and C,B,A is added to backstack.But when i press back from D animation specified in onCreate is triggered instead of the animation in the onBackPressed.Also when i press back from B to A onBackPressed animation is triggered .This doesnt happen if i navigate from A to D and then i press back, so animation in onCreate is taking over animation in onBackPressed .So what is happening there and how to solve this?
Thank you in advance

I am using this abstract activity in A,B,C

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
int listId;
String[] data=new String[]{};
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
String title;
String resourceName;
int holderId;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    setContentView(R.layout.recycler);
    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    toolbar.setTitle(title);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (listId==0)
        listId=this.getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName,"array",this.getPackageName());
    data=this.getResources().getStringArray(listId);
    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        list.add(data[i]);
    RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)this.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,null));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter=new CardAdapter(list,holderId,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}



public AbstractActivity(String title,int listId,int holderId){
   /*
   title is the title for the activity
   listId is the string array resource id for data used by the recyclerView
   holderId is the layout resource used as viewHolder by the recycler used by the CardAdapter
    */
 this.title=title;
 this.listId=listId;
 this.holderId=holderId;
}
```

I am extendig this class in activity A(MainActivity):

```
public class MainActivity extends AbstractActivity {
 Class activityClass;
 public MainActivity(){
      super("VTU Student",R.array.main_page_options,R.layout.main_page);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 String item= (String) v.getTag();
 final String className=item.replaceAll(" |\\.","");
   try {
         activityClass=Class.forName("android.anoop.com.vtustudent."+className);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final Context context=this;
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,activityClass);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    },600);
}
}
```

Activities B and C also extends AbstractActivity.

As for Activity D(Subjects):

```
public class Subjects extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
String branch="";
int listId;
String[] data=new String[]{};
List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    branch=getIntent().getStringExtra("branch");
    setContentView(R.layout.recycler);
    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    toolbar.setTitle("Subjects");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    listId=getResources().getIdentifier(branch,"array",getPackageName());
    data=this.getResources().getStringArray(listId);
    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        list.add(data[i]);
    RecyclerView recyclerView=(RecyclerView)this.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, null));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter=new CardAdapter(list,R.layout.recycler_list_holder,this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
    @Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
}
```

And animation files are:
pull_in_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:duration="700"
android:fromXDelta="-100%"
android:toXDelta="0%"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
/>
```

pull_in_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:duration="700"
android:fromXDelta="100%"
android:toXDelta="0%"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
/>
```

push_out_left:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:duration="700"
android:fromXDelta="0%"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:toXDelta="-100%" />
```

push_out_right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:duration="700"
android:fromXDelta="0%"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
android:toXDelta="100%" />
```

Comment: The onCreate is fired because the Activities in the backstack were never created. Each activity is created when back is pressed. You will have to change the activity enter/exit animations in the activity's theme in your styles.xml file

Comment: then what does startActivities() do? Also the onBackPressed animation is triggered for B->A and not for D->C or C->B, that is what i am not able to understand

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit of a hack but i was not able to find what was actually going on.
I set a sharedPreference when back was pressed:

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getSharedPreferences("OtherInfo",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putBoolean("backPressed",true);
    editor.commit();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
}
```

Then in its parent activity i put a check for backPressed , if it is false(When back was not pressed) i execute the animation code else i set backPressed to false so that it may not interfere when entering the activity from its parent activity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (!getSharedPreferences("OtherInfo",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("backPressed",false)) {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
    }
    else
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getSharedPreferences("OtherInfo",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("backPressed",false);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

And this is giving the result as expected.